# Matlab-frequency bin of the positive and negative frequency

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, fft

I am using MATLAB tutorial [Frequency-Domain Linear Regression](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ug/frequency-domain-linear-regression.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com). There is one part of code, where is necessary to determine "frequency bin of the positive and negative frequency", for fft and ifft, this part of code:

```
freqbin = 72/12;
freqbins = [freqbin 72-freqbin]+1;
tsfit = zeros(72,1);
tsfit(freqbins) = tsdft(freqbins);
tsfit = ifft(tsfit);
mu = mean(ts);
tsfit = mu+tsfit;
```

Length of time series is 72, and there is 12 months is one cycle. How there can be only one frequency bin for positive frequency, how do we know that is exactly 72/12+1 (+1 is because first bin is for zero frequency), is that some formula or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with some general notes. If the sample rate is `Fs`, and the number of samples in the FFT is `N`, then the frequency of the bin with MATLAB index `k` is:

```
f_k = (k-1) * Fs / N ;
```

Or, conversely,

```
k = f_k * N / Fs + 1;
```

Hence, the elements of the FFT vector correspond to frequencies `0, Fs/N, 2*Fs/N, ..., (N-1)*Fs/N`.

Note that the frequencies are invariant to shifts by `Fs`. In other words, `f` and `f+Fs` and `f-Fs` are all equivalent. So, you could consider the first half of the FFT vector to correspond to positive frequencies (index: 1 to N/2; frequency: `0` to `(N/2-1)/N*Fs`), and the second half to correspond to negative frequencies (index: N/2+1 to N; frequency: `-Fs/2` to `-Fs/N`). Here I include 0 in the set of positive frequencies for brevity.

Now, coming to your specific example:

```
N  = 72
Fs = 12 ; % samples per year
```

So, the positive frequency range is from `0` to `Fs/2 = 6` cycles per year, corresponding to indices 1 to 36, respectively.

You are interested in finding the FFT sample corresponding to the frequency 1 cycle per year. That corresponds to index `1 * 72 / 12 + 1 = 7`.
Since the FFT is symmetric for real signals, you are also interested in finding the FFT sample corresponding to the frequency -1 cycle per year, which, using the shift-invariance property, is also equivalent to `-1 + Fs = 11` cycles per year. The corresponding index is `(12-1) * 72 / 12 + 1 = 67`.

In summary,

- There are 36 positive frequencies  (including 0), not 1.
- The algorithm is interested in only one positive frequency with the highest magnitude.
- That frequency happens to be 1 cycle per year. The corresponding MATLAB index is 7.
- The mirror image of the frequency is -1 cycle per year, which corresponds to MATLAB index 67.

Comment: Thanks. What if in my example lenght of time series is odd number, that corresponds to index which is decimal number? Fs is also 12.

Can you explain again "Note that the frequencies are invariant to shifts by Fs. In other words, f and f+Fs and f-Fs are all equivalent."

Comment: Indices _greater than or equal to_ N/2+1 can be considered negative irrespective of whether N is even or odd. The relationship between f_k and k, described by the top two equations in the answer, holds for any value of N. About frequency shift invariance: This has to do with discrete time representation. Do this experiment: plot two sinusoids, with frequencies 1 kHz and 49 kHz respectively, sampled at 48 kHz. Do they look the same? Any two sinusoids separated by frequency Fs would be indistinguishable. [More details.](http://allsignalprocessing.com/discrete-time-frequency-avoid-confusion/)

Comment: But what if I get that k is decimal number? I need to use k later like index for series of Fourier coefficients?

Comment: @nick_name If `k` is fractional then it is often okay to round it to the nearest integer. But it really depends on the application. You could also use longer FFT size, like `X = fft(x, N)`. The spacing of the frequency bins is a function of `N`, which can be greater than the length of `x`. For more details, read up on zero-padding in FFT.